# Adding php to javascript (wordpress)

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, date

I am got using following code in a javascript file(custom.js):

```
gapinvite = new Date(2014, 06 - 1, 2);
$('.days').countdown({
    until: gapinvite,
    layout: '{dn} {dl}',
    timezone: +7
});
```

I am using theme options(theme-options.php) to get the input from a user and then need to use it in the above javascript file.If it was a php file I would've used:

```
$date = get_option('director_date');
if( $date) {
echo $date;
}
```

. Since it is a javascript file I do not know how that could be possible. Could you please help?

Comment: There are a lot of introductions to AJAX which you can find in Google. And that's how to use AJAX in WP http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins.

Comment: I'm not good at ajax.An answer would be appreciated

Comment: you want to add php code to javascript file ?

Comment: Yes.Or an alternative would be appreciated

Comment: you can add javascript to php file and the include the php file where you want

Comment: Well it is in wordpress. That wouldn't work.

Comment: it will work ,include your file in index.php

Comment: How would i include my file .Now custom.php inside it? I believe i need to use function.php. Or directly into index.php?

Comment: Alright so i am using <?php require_once('custom.php'); ?> inside functions.php but it doesn't work

Comment: what problem you facing when you do so

Comment: The script doesn't run.The browser crashes. When custom.js is used it runs

Comment: Alright now the browser is not crashing with custom.php but the script doesn't run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Output the value into a javascript variable during rendering.

```
<script>var directorDate = new Date(<?php echo date('Y, m, d', $date); ?>);</script>
```

Then in the javascript, reference directorDate variable.

The script tag above needs to be inserted before your custom.js, or custom.js needs to wait before looking for the variable (it will be undefined otherwise).

Comment: during rendering? Do you mean i need to add the above code to theme-options.php"

Comment: While the page is being created on the server. For example, add the code above to your header.php template file in the <head> section if it should be available on all pages.

Comment: And how do i reference it. Once added?

Comment: In JavaScript it will be "directorDate".

Comment: you mean console.log("directorDate")?

Comment: All right so i have added the above code to the head. Now i need to reference it. Could you please tell what i need to change in custom.js(first code in question)?

Comment: Thank you so much. I had to modify it a lot. But the concept was the same. Thank you.

Comment: Could you have a look at this question of mine. The above code led to a slight problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22409271/linking-php-and-javascript-error-in-wordpress