# Linking php and javascript error in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I have got a javascript(jquery) file called custom.js in which i am using:

```
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.days').countdown({
            until: directorDate,
            layout: '{dn} {dl}',
            timezone: +7
        });
        $('#weather').openWeather({
            city: 'directorCity //The city is in a string.It used to be 'New York,US'
            placeTarget: '.weather-place',
            iconTarget: '.weather-icon',
            customIcons: 'dark/files/img/icons/weather/'
        });
        });
})(jQuery);
```

In my header i am using:

```
<script>var directorDate = new Date(<?php $date = get_option('director_date');?>
<?php if( $date) : ?>
<?php echo $date; ?>
<?php endif; ?>);
var directorCity = <?php $city = get_option('director_city');?>
<?php if( $city) : ?>
<?php echo $city; ?>
<?php endif; ?></script>
```

Basically what is happening is that the header gets the data from a file themeoptions.php (A form in the wordpress admin for a user to input data.I have not shown it because the structure of both director_city and director_date is the same there) and then custom.js gets the data from the header.

Now the countdown runs however the city is not displayed. Why is that so?

Comment: What is the output of the javascript?

Comment: what happens if you echo $city? In other words, remove the if

Answer (score 1):

You need to echo the value from php, not put it in a variable.

Comment: The browser crashes :(

Answer (score 1):

You should probably echo the value instead of assigning it to a php variable like so:

```
var directorCity = <?php echo $get_option('director_city');?>
```

EDIT: It's not entirely sure to me what you are trying to accomplish, you could perhaps try the following for tbe head:

```
<script>
var directorDate = new Date(<?php echo get_option('director_date');?>
var directorCity = <?php echo get_option('director_city');?>
</script>
```

Comment: The browser crashes :(

Comment: The city is in a string. Should've mentioned it. It used to be 'New York,US'

Comment: If you echo your php variable the browser crashes? That doesn't make sense. Can you show the code?

Answer (score 0):

If your site is no longer working there is probably a error in your php. Please post your code here.

This sort of thing is best done using [wp_localize_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script), but if you want to output it directly try something like this, think it's a bit more readable than the other answers:

```
//use ternary operator to check, otherwise we want an empty string
$director_date = get_option('director_date') ? get_option('director_date') : '';
$director_city = get_option('director_city') ? get_option('director_city') : '';

?>

<script>
    var directorCity = <?php echo $director_city; ?> ;
    var directorDate = <?php echo $director_date; ?> ;
</script>
```

Also I don't know if it's just a typing error in the code here or is actually in your javascript but in your options for `openWeather` you are passing

```
city: 'directorCity'
```

rather than

```
city: directorCity
```